# Topology of direct product of $ F_{p}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, topological-groups

Let's assume that $F$ is a number field, $R^{*}$ =$\prod_{P\in S}$$F_{P}$, $R$ is the Adele ring of $F$ and
$$
R' = \prod_{P\in S_{0}}\mathfrak{o}_{\mathfrak{p}}\times\prod_{P\in S_{\infty}}F_{P}.$$

Let $\{O\}$ be the family of all neighborhoods of $0$ in $R'$. We define a topology on $R$ by taking $\{\alpha+O\}$ as a base of neighborhoods of $\alpha$ in $R$. Then $R$ is a topological ring and $R'$ is an open subring of $R$.

**Question**. Is it true that $R^{*}$ is not a topological ring, if we define a topology in $R^{*}$ by taking $\{\beta+O\}$ as a base of neighborhoods of $\beta \in R^{*}$?

I tried to prove it by using the definition of a topological ring but failed because I didn't find a good way to prove that the operations of the ring are not continuous.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't explain your notation $S_0$ and $S_\infty$. Presumably $S_\infty$ is the set of infinite places of $F$, but what is $S_0$: the finite places?   Your question reminds me of the fact that the idele group of $F$, equipped with its subspace topology as a subset of the adele ring of $F$, is not a topological group since inversion is not continuous for that subspace topology on the ideles of $F$.   For the case $F = \mathbf Q$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3899761/topology-on-the-idele-group.

Comment: $S_{0}$ is the set of finite places and $S_{\infty}$ is the set of infinite places.